# Using dynamic links to external workbooks in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, macros, vba

I have a master workbook that needs to pull data from a specific dated subfolder. The date is specified by the user prior to macros being run.

The master workbook acts only as a presentation layer,  and the source/underlying data in the dated subfolders have consistent names and formats.

Assume that within my master workbook on 'Sheet1' I have the following function in `A1`:

```
='C:\Development\GridsResults\20101115\[DATA_sheet_20101115_D.xlsx]Stresses'!$C$9
```

You will notice that are two 'dated' parts in the file link - this needs to be supplied by the user. In this case, the date supplied is `15-Nov-2010`. Now if the user supplies `23-Nov-2010`, the above link should be

```
='C:\Development\GridsResults\20101120\[DATA_sheet_20101120_D.xlsx]Stresses'!$C$9
```

I already have a formulae that create the above file paths, within my `Links` sheet in my master workbook. This is the dynamic part which creates the links. Now in the `Links` sheet, assume that result of my magic resides in cell `B3` and is a named Range called `DATA` i.e.

```
C:\Development\GridsResults\20101120\[DATA_sheet_20101120_D.xlsx]
```

So in theory, what the outcome should be, is that cell `A1` on `Sheet1` in my master workbook should use this generated file path

```
="'" & DATA & "Stresses'!$C$9
```

Is there a combination of standard excel functions that can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=INDIRECT("'" & DATA & "Stresses'!$C$9")`.

Comment: doesn't the referenced workbook need to be opened to use this?

Comment: yes it need to be opened

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this would be possible using the standard Excel functions. if it is it would definitely not look pretty.

I think your best bet would be to create a macro; the activation method would be up to you, of course. The macro would look something like this.

```
Dim L1 As Variant, L2 As Variant
L1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("DATA").RefersToRange
L2 = "='" & L1 & "Stresses'!R9C3"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = L2
```

Answer (score 0):

http://numbermonger.com/2012/02/11/excel-pull-function-creating-dynamic-links-to-closed-workbooks/

The Link above vcould be a good option. Didn't had the time to test it myself.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or disappears.

Comment: And this is such case right now. Domain does not exist.